# How to correctly synchronize and reuse the ForkJoinPool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

This is a example:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();  
pool.submit(new RecursiveTaskA());  
// wait the task to finish  
doSomethingElse();  

pool.submit(new RecursiveTaskB());
...
```

**Question 1:**
How to ensure the RecursiveTaskA is finished before calling **doSomethingElse()**?
Currently my solution is:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();  
pool.submit(new RecursiveTaskA());  

pool.shutdown();  
pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);  

// wait the task to finish  
doSomethingElse();
```

Is this the correct way? Or is there a better way?
**Question 2:**
If I use the solution above, then **pool.submit(new RecursiveTaskB());** result errors. I don't want to make a new ForkJoinPool, how to do it?

Any link, reference would be helpful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undertand your problem correctly, you can just [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#join--) the submitted task:

```
RecursiveTaskA taskA = new RecursiveTaskA();
pool.submit(taskA);
taskA.join();
doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: taskA creates subtasks recursively, so I have to call join() for each subtask internally right? If I don't, it seems that the program terminates before these subtasks get executed.

Comment: Properly written `taskA` should finish only when all the forked subtasks are finished. That's why it's fork-join task: you first fork (create subtasks), then join (wait them to finish and combine the result). If it's not the case, consider rewriting `RecursiveTaskA`.